# Why do golfers yell: “Fore”?

Tags: meaning

Feeling rather bogeyed, I'm looking for some fore-closure to this query — help!

Comment: Oh, come on, Arthur. We know you know the answer to this, and we know you know we know you know it.

Comment: Sucksex!! You've ex-posited my dangling participle for the world to see,man......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most interesting.  I lways knew it was a traditional warning cry while golfing, but I just googled it and there is sever possible sources

[Cut paste and some editing from WIKIPEDIA]

It is mentioned as early as 1881. The term means "look ahead", and it is believed to come from the military "beware before", which was shouted when a battery fired behind friendly troops.
- This one sounds most likely to me - it just fits with the Scots and the British history as I know it.

Other possible origins include the term being derived from the term "fore-caddy", a caddy waiting down range from the golfer to find where the ball lands.

It also may have a contraction of the Gaelic cry Faugh a Ballach! (i.e. Clear the way!) which is still associated with the sport of road bowling which has features reminiscent of golf.

=When I get to work I'll try to look it up in the OED and see when it was first used in written form.

Comment: How do you pronounce "Faugh a Ballach" in Gaelic? Presumably 'huh'?

Comment: From what I've read, the term "fore-caddy" has the most plausibility. The golfer would yell at the fore-caddy to look for the incoming ball, and I reckon it would take one round to shorten "FORECADDY!" to "FORE!"

Answer (score 1):

"Fore" in this sense is the same as in a book's "foreword," i.e., "that which goes before." Or even, the 'fore' in "before." Means "those in the fore should look out - here comes a shot."